# PAYTR IFRAME failed. reason:Required field value is invalid or not sent (get-token): email

Tags: woocommerce, iframe

Hi I was trying to Add Paytr payment method to my website but it is giving me this error PAYTR IFRAME failed. Reason: Required field value is invalid or could not be sent (get-token): gives email error I asked this and they told me this. E-mail content cannot be sent, which is a required field specified in the integration document, how can I fix this?

They Said To Default Your Woocomerce Payment Page But I Don't Know How To Do It